# JS - Query MIN \ MAX Value between 2 different Numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am not very well in Java Script and i didn't found a solution for my problem.

I have a textbox on my page where inside i am authorized to write a number between 0 and 199.

If i write 200 or >, then i want to get an alert (onblur).

I found a code who is very interesting and maybe useful.

But I don't know if he works, because I don't know how to implement this.

```
<script>
    var min = 0;
    var max = 199;
    var num = parseInt(myform.numfield.value);
    if (min > num || max < num) {
        alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I Hope you can help me

Here the new code who works

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Page</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check(min, max) {
                var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_one').value);
                if (min > num || max < num)
                {
                    alert(num + ' ist nicht zwischen ' + min + ' und ' + max);
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form> 
            Zahl: <input type='text' id='value_one' onBlur="check(0, 100)" > 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I have also another question. Is it possible to add to the same function a query, where, when I write a number bigger than 99 into the same Textbox, where we have the query of MIN and MAX, to get an alert with a Message "Now we get new values", but still when I write 200 or bigger, to get the Message like before. Is it possible? Thank you very much so late for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put this code into a function, and then call it onblur:

```
function check(min, max) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value);
    if (min > num || max < num) {
        alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
    }
}
```

and then

```
<input type='text' onblur="check(0, 199)"
```

Comment: Hi Adam, i have tried your solution, but it doesn't works.
Perhaps the JS code has an error? And i forget to tell, it must working on Internet explorer 6! Thank you for your help, cheers

Comment: @achillix - that code should work fine in IE6.  Can you please post the code you tried as an update to your question?

Comment: That is all what i have now:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function check(min, max) {
    var num = parseInt(this.value);
    if (min > num || max < num) {
        alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
        Value: <input type='text' onblur="check(0, 199)" >
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @achillix - do you get any errors in the your console window?  What's happening?  Have you tried putting an alert at the very beginning of the check function to make sure it's getting called at all?

Comment: No nothing, i don't know whats happened. If you have tested the code? If you have get an error? THX

Comment: You need to run the code in Chrome or FireFox (with FireBug), and see if you get any errors.  Also try putting an alert at the beginning of your check function to see if the function is being called at all

Comment: Hi, sorry that i answer so late. I have tested now the script in Firefox with the plugin Firebug. I don't get the alert message and i can't find errors in the console. In Script / Stack, i get this: onblur()onblur (Line 2)
event = blur  

If you have vound something?

Comment: @achillix - post all of your relevant code—html and javascript—as an update to your question

Comment: Hi, it works now ;-) I use document.getElementById and it works, also on IE6. Here the whole code:
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Page</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check(min, max) { 
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_one').value);
if (min > num || max < num) 
{ alert(num + ' ist nicht zwischen ' + min + ' und ' + max); 
} 
}  
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form> 
Zahl: <input type='text' id='value_one' onBlur="check(0, 100)" > 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>

Comment: I have also another question. Is it possible to add to the same function a query, where, when i write a number bigger than 99 into the same Textbox, where we have the query of MIN and MAX, to get an alert with a Message "Now we get new values", but still when i write 200 or bigger, to get the Message like before.
Is it possible?
Thank you very much so late for your help. Cheers

Comment: @achillix - I don't follow.  You'll probably want to post a new question asking what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, for future reference, you should post code into an edit to your question, not a comment.

Comment: You are right, i will create a new question tomorrow, so it will be clearer.
Thank you , cheers

Answer (score 1):

Put the code you found in a function

```
  function minMax(){
      var min=0;
      var max = 199;
      var num = parseInt(myform.numfield.value);
      if (min > num || max < num) {
          alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
          return false;
      }
  }
```

And then call it when your form field is blurred

```
var formField = document.getElementById('elementID'); //or however you want to get it
formField.onblur = minMax();
```

That'll do it.

Comment: Hi, thank you to for your help. I tried your solution, but i get not an alert. I gave an id to the element (input textbox) where i write the number, but nothing. Where i put the second code: var formField = document.getElementById('elementID'); //or however you want to get it
formField.onblur = minMax();

Answer (score 0):

Here by a complete HTML: (just save it and try it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page)</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
        var min=0;
        var max = 100;
        var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('value_one').value);
        console.log(num);
        if (min > num || max < num) {
            alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
        return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myform" action="submit-form.php">
        Value: <input type='number' id='value_one' name='value_one'>
        <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE ANSWER TO MATCH YOUR COMMENT:**

This is the moment where I think: use a proven library, like jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(){
            var enteredValue = $("input:#value_one").val();
            var min=0;
            var max = 100;
            var num = parseInt(enteredValue);

            if (min > num || max < num) {
                alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
                return false;
            }
       });

    //  or listen to your textfield blur event: /////////////////////
    //  $("input:#value_one").blur(function() {
    //      var enteredValue = $("input:#value_one").val();
    //      var min=0;
    //      var max = 100;
    //      var num = parseInt(enteredValue);

    //      if (min > num || max < num) {
    //          alert(num + ' is not between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
    //          return false;
    //      }   
    //  });
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myform" action="submit-form.php">
        Value: <input type='string' id='value_one' name='value_one'>
        <a href="#">Submit</a>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

With the help of jQuery you can bind to the `blur()` event or just as above on a submit or a hyperlink. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, it works, but not in IE6, i forget to explain that, if you know why? And if it is possible to make this code working on IE6? Big THX

Comment: Hi
That looks interesting, i will try it.
Thank you very much

Cheers